# Exit an app on dialog button click

Tags: java, android

I am trying to exit an app when ever the user clicks the back button let it display a dialog yes/no button on clicking the yes button let it exit the app including with the registration activity assuming you are on the main activity.

This is my code but it not working

```
private AlertDialog AskOption()
{
   AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox =new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
       .setTitle("Exit") 
       .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?") 
      // .setIcon(R.drawable.delete)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
//at this point i am trying to exit the app
               Register reg = new Register();
               reg.finish();
               finish();
               System.exit(0);

           }   
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dialog.dismiss();
           }
       })
       .create();
       return myQuittingDialogBox;

   }
```

when the back button is clicked on the main activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    AlertDialog diaBox = AskOption();
    diaBox.show();

}
```

How do I exit the app from the mainactivity including the register activity on yes button click of the dialog

Comment: `new Register();`... Never make an Activity like that

Comment: check for back stack count  the count is 0 then activity.finish will do

Comment: I think it could be duplicated with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591959/android-quit-application-when-press-back-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code.

```
  .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    //at this point i am trying to exit the app
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
              intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
              intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
              startActivity(intent);
              finish();
              System.exit(0);

               }   
           })
```

#### Note :

if you used `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` then it can clean the History of Activity.

Comment: @Blaze did you try it or not ?

Comment: This clears everything including any previous activity than just stepping in to include finish() at those previous activity. DRY principle

Comment: Does this also remove the app from recents?

Comment: @esfox no this code not remove the app from the recent. for that you have to used `android:excludeFromRecents="true"`. in the Activity define in `Mainfest`

Answer (score 1):

```
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
           finish();
       }   
   })
```

Doing `finish();` on click should be enough.

Comment: This navigates me to the Register activity

Comment: @Blaze you have to finish application when you navigate from register activity to another activity

Comment: You approach is equally correct. Finishing activity before moving to the next

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nice except following:

> Register reg = new Register();
>
> reg.finish();

Remove these code of lines and onBackButtonPress.

```
 Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your setPositiveButton

```
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
           finish();
           System.exit(0);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.exit(0); is only enough to exit from App. But finishing activity before exiting App would be good. 
So you can write the code like this,

.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

```
           finish();
           System.exit(0);

       }   
   })
```

It worked for me.